# existence of specific generators of $F_2$

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $F_2=\langle a,b\rangle$ be the free group generated by $a$ and $b$, $W^*$ the words of $\{a,\overline{a},b,\overline{b}\}$ and $w \in W^*$ be a reduced word (I am actually looking for an "asymmetric word" so you can assume $w=a^k b$ for some large enough $k$ if this helps). The question is then:

> Can we find two generators $s,t \in F_2$ satisfying the following
> conditions:
>
> - $s$ and $t$ are cyclically reduced
> - $s$ and $t$ have as common start $w$, i.e. we have as reduced words $s=w s'$ and $t=w t'$ with $s',t' \in W^*$ and $s'$ and $t'$ are non-empty and start
>   with different letters
> - $s$ and $t$ end with different letters

This question arose in the construction of a counterexample, namely I need in the Cayley-graph of the free group generators whose translation-axes intersect in a most asymmetric way (or are far away, which is not possible for $F_2$). After several (obviously fruitless) attempts to construct such $s$ and $t$ I forward this question now to you.

Comment: $a^kb$ and $a^kba$ seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, $s'$ and $t'$ should not be empty. Else the translation axis of $s$ is just a repetition $a^kba^kb$ and so metaphorically spoken $s'$ and $t'$ "start" with the same letter. Actually it wouldn't matter if $s'$ where empty, but then $t'$ has to start and end with a different letters than $w$.

Comment: If you want both $s'$ and $t'$ to be non-empty then this is impossible (I am assuming by "two generators" you mean "a generating pair"): The (folded) Stallings' graph corresponding to such a pair is a $\theta$-graph, with the central line corresponding to $W$ and the two other edges corresponding to $s'$ and $t'$. Your assumptions mean that all three edges have length $\geq1$. However, bases of $F_2$ have Stallings' graph equal to the bouquet with a single vertex and two loop edges, labelled $a$ and $b$ respectively, and so $\langle s, t\rangle\neq\langle a, b\rangle$.

Comment: To see if I remember this correctly (please correct my mistakes): Starting with our rose with labels $s$ and $t$, then we have that $s$ and $t$ are generators iff the iterated folding (according to our word) ends at some point at the rose with labels $a$ and $b$. If this is correctly remembered, then you are right, you should post this as an answer.

Comment: Okay, great! I wasn't sure if you would know what Stallings' graphs are :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, this was actually quite elegant. I fear now, that the intersection in the original problem might always be symmetric (in some sense), but that will be a problem for another day :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "two generators" you mean "a generating pair", so $\langle s,t\rangle=F(a, b)$, this is impossible.

The (folded) Stallings' graph corresponding to your a pair $(s, t)$ is a $\theta$-graph, with the central line corresponding to $W$ and the two other edges corresponding to $s′$ and $t′$. The assumptions in the question mean that all three edges have length $\geq1$. However, bases of $F(a, b)$ have Stallings' graph equal to the bouquet with a single vertex and two loop edges, labelled $a$ and $b$ respectively, and so $\langle s,t\rangle\neq F(a, b)$ as claimed.